# Presence integration with Outlook 2013

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, office-interop

I am trying to integrate my IM-client, written in C#, with MS Outlook 2013. I would like Outlook to receive presence information from my IM-client. First shot was to use this [instruction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj900715.aspx).

It worked well in the beginning (Outlook get my interface, check for version and features, abilities to start conversation), but in the chapter "Retrieving contact presence" I've got a difference. Outlook didn't call "GetContactInformation" as described. It isn't work for neither interface returned for version "15.0.0.0" nor "14.0.0.0".

I've tried to turn on logging using OfficePresenceLogging, but it appeared to be available only for previous versions of MS Outlook. So, I used [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/a174ca43-cdcf-4f78-a032-8e0cf6d29080/officepresencelogging-in-outlook-2013) technique, which gave me binary file "Microsoft Support Engineer has the tools to analyze".

Since I use Windows 8.1, LorParser 2.2 unable to read this file, and TraceRpt.exe is only able to give me metadata (like time or Process ID). The important part of the log is hidden beneath BinaryEventData field. I could translate those hexes to ascii and see something like a methods names and garbage.

I wonder if someone could advise me something:

1. Is it possible to read Office 2013 logs to troubleshoot my IM integration?
2. Is there any hints that could I check to find a problem?

Answer (score 1):

I come up with some solution, so I want to write down an answer. I hope it can be useful for someone.

1. Unfortunately I failed to read Outlook 2013 logs in both Windows 8.1 and Windows 7. The only solution I've found: test the application with Office 2010 (it uses text logs). You can find instructions how to turn on logs at the end of this [article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff678502%28v=ocs.14%29.aspx).

In my case the first error I've got was:
"CMsoProviderOCom::HrEnsureContactAndGroupManager !failed!  Line: 3998  hr = 0x80040200"

2. It seems Outlook reject all further information if something went wrong at the beginning of the integration with IM.

   - Check your application returns all correct values for the methods Outlook uses.
   - Check you've implemented all events, it seems impossible to find lack of them with debugger.
   - Take a look at Lync SDK. It has the similar interface (Microsoft.Lync.Model) and it's documentation looks more complete.

In my case I just forgot to mark couple of my classes with [ComSourceInterfaces()].

Comment: Thank you. Almost 8 years later, your question and answer helped me. I forgot to mark one of my classes with `[ComSourceInterfaces()]` as well - the `Contact` implementation should be marked with `[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(_IContactEvents))]`. Without that mark, Outlook 2016 gives up after calling `ContactManager.Lookup()` and `Contact.GetContactInformation(ucPresenceInstantMessageAddresses)`.